# How do I center my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I realize that the left two containers are not as wide as my div `addons` but regardless I'd at least like everything to be centered with an even amount of empty space on the left and right of everything. But I can't seem to figure it out. It is a little messy I admit with all of the `display: inline-block` and `float:left` I have going on, but even the usual

```
margin-left:auto
margin-right:auto
width: 600px
```

isn't of much help to me right now. And I'd like to center without setting a random `margin-left` property that won't render the same at every resolution. Can anyone please assist?

The site in question is https://com-bb-dev.com.edu

Thank you for your expertise.

Comment: You cannot use the `margin: auto` trick if the element is floated.

Comment: ya you almost had it just use: { margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; } no floats

Comment: Where do I have to get rid of the floats? I want the login and announcements pane to be on the left as it's own "column" of info and the featured items and browser checker to be on the right as it's own "column". Will removing the floats enable this?

Comment: Add a fixed width (ie `width: 600px;`, `display: block;` and `margin: 0 auto` to the wrapper. that is everything required to center an element. No floats, positions, right/lefts, etc else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are not laying out the page correctly.

Consider the following (LOTR reference):

1. One div to contain them all.
2. Seven divs for the dwarf-lords floating left (in their halls of stone).
3. Three divs for the elven kings floating right (under the sky).
4. These divs and more will center on your page (where the shadows lie).

Center the One div on the page and put the other divs inside this div.

Comment: This makes the most sense, I'll try it and report.

Comment: Thank you! I applied this and was able to make it work. I wrapped all of the divs related to the login field and the announcements in a dummy div called "floatContainer", set it to float:left, and then set my div "addons" to float:right, got rid of the floats on everything else, and then set the left/right margins to auto and my width to 1345px for #loginPageContainer and received my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you just set the #loginPageContainer on the page you linked to width:600px; then it works. Just tried it myself in developer tools.

It is the wrapper-element that has to be centered. Not each div, if there are floated elements on the same "level", it will break.

Comment: Setting the width to that ID just messes up the entire page, though.

Comment: So the "featured elements", and "Browser check" be on the right? If so, you have to wrap the two boxes and center the wrapper. Not the boxes themselves.

Comment: If you set #loginPageContainer to width: 1345; , is that what you want? Then the entire site with these two elements are centered.

Comment: I didn't realize you had mentioned setting the width to 1345, but that was what I had found it to center on so I am going to give you an up vote for having said that.

Comment: Actually yours and DwB answers are theoretically the same, wish I could give you both a green check :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, just change the values in it so it fit yours

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```